# Yarn Offline Mirroring Doesn't Work As Expected

Tags: node-modules, yarnpkg, package-managers

Trying to utilise [yarn offline mirroring](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/), and it's not working as I expect.

**How I expect it to work:**

Tarballs get saved in a cache folder, as specified in the `.yarnrc`, and `yarn install --offline` extracts those into `node_modules` in up to 5 seconds and everyone is happy.

**How it seems to (not) work:**

After I did everything described in the doc above, I:

- Delete `node_modules`
- Try to `yarn install --offline` again with my wifi turned off.

This results in a failure in the `Linking dependecies...` step (3rd one after Resolving & Fetching). The error is a package (chromedriver) trying to use internet connection and also seems to be a symptom and not the actual problem.

Fetching step is very quick, so it does seem like it finds the local tarballs, but why does the linking take so long? I'm talking about 4-5~ minutes of a `yarn install` step each time, which eventually takes pretty much the same amount of time, thus gaining me nothing overall except for lots of binaries in my repo.

Is the process itself faulty? Am I doing anything wrong, or not running the correct commands? The docs are not clear, to say the least.